Convert ASCII char array to long and long to char array
But the conversion fails at value 128.
public long asciiToLong(char[] in) {
    CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(in);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.encode(charBuffer);
    
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(byteArray);

    long result = ByteBuffer.wrap(new String(byteArray).getBytes()).getLong();
    return result;
}

public char[] longToAscii(long in) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
    buffer.putLong(in);
    byte[] b =  buffer.array();
    CharBuffer charBuffer = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(b));

    char[] result = new char[charBuffer.remaining()];
    charBuffer.get(result);
    
    return result;
}

When I test it with the following code it fails at 128.
for (long l = 0 ; l < 100000 ; l++) {
    char[] ascii = longToAscii(l);
    System.out.printf("%d -> ", l);
    long l2 = asciiToLong(ascii);
    System.err.printf("%d\n", l2);
    if (l != l2) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

Output :
    0 -> 0
    1 -> 1
    2 -> 2
    3 -> 3
    // console output truncated..
    126 -> 126
    127 -> 127
    128 -> 63 // fails

Changing the StandardCharset used to decode the long integer fails at the same position with different value.

EDIT
I finally achieved it without using an encoding, though it surely can be optimized.
public long asciiToLong(char[] in) {
    long result = byteArrayToLong(charArrayToByteArray(in));
    return result;
}

public char[] longToAscii(long in) {
    byte[] bs = longToByteArray(in);
    char[] result = new char[bs.length];
    int i = bs.length;
    for (byte b : bs) {
        i--;
        result[i] = (char) b;
    }
    return result;
}

private long byteArrayToLong(byte[] b) {
    long result = 0;
    for (byte value : b) {
        result <<= Byte.SIZE;
        result |= (value & 0xFF);
    }
    return result;
}

private byte[] charArrayToByteArray(char[] charArray) {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[charArray.length];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < charArray.length ; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = (byte) (0xFF & (int) charArray[i]);
    }
    return byteArray;
}

private byte[] longToByteArray(long v) {
    byte[] b = new byte[Long.BYTES];
    int i = 0;
    int[] j = { 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56 };
    while (i < Long.BYTES) {
        b[i] = (byte)(v >>> j[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return b;
}

Testing it with the following code
long l;
long l2;
for (l = 0 ; l < 100000 ; l++) {
    char[] ascii = longToAscii(l);
    System.out.printf("%d->", l);
    l2 = asciiToLong(ascii);
    System.out.printf("%d\n", l2);
    if (l != l2) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

Shows the following output with no errors
    0 -> 0
    1 -> 1
    2 -> 2
    3 -> 3
    // console output truncated..
    99999 -> 99999


What is the purpose of this? If you just want to round trip between the bytes in a long and the bytes in a char[], you should not involve an encoding. Encoding and decoding the bytes potentially modifies the bytes, and that is exactly what is happening here.

This is expected. Characters are not simply sequences of bytes. A Charset determines how a sequence of characters is transformed into a sequence of bytes and how a sequence of bytes is transformed into a sequence of characters. This transformation differs for different Charsets (otherwise there would be no point in having different Charsets). US_ASCII for example defines a mapping for byte values 0 to 127, everything else is invalid in represented as '?' - the value 63.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but in your first method, you convert characters to bytes using the US_ASCII character set, then you convert those bytes back to characters via new String(byteArray) which uses your platform's default character set, which is unlikely to be US_ASCII.  So you end up with possibly different characters.

Thanks for your explanation. The purpose of this is to convert a long value into a char array and vice versa. I'm trying to avoid the charset encoding.

There is no point repeating the title - HOW exactly do you want to convert a long value (ONE value) into a char  array (MANY values) ? For example, what char[] is expected for 123456L? (Or for 99999L, as for posted code)

You need to state your goal

@user85421 I edited the question with some code providing the expected result.

You did not provide HOW, neither what is expected in the char[] - quoting/repeating myself "what char[] is expected for 123456L"...  based on given example :  use Long.toString(value).toCharArray() and Long.valueOf(new String(array))

From your code, it looks like you just want to round-trip between the bytes in a long and the bytes in a char[]. You should not involve an charset.
Encoding and decoding the bytes potentially modifies the bytes, and that is exactly what is happening here. Charset.encode and Charset.decode both handle invalid byte sequences (the long value 128 is such a sequence) by replacing it with a replacement character. This is why your implementation does not round-trip.
Theoretically, you can use an charset for which all 256 byte values are valid characters, and this would work. I don't know of such a charset though. Note that you should also use the same charset when doing new String(...) and String.getBytes(...).
Here is an implementation of the pair of methods that do not involve a charset, and round-tripping works.
public static long asciiToLong(char[] in) {
    var buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(in.length * Character.BYTES);
    for (char c : in) {
        buffer.putChar(c);
    }
    return buffer.flip().getLong();
}

public static char[] longToAscii(long in) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
    buffer.putLong(in);
    char[] result = new char[Long.BYTES / Character.BYTES];
    buffer.flip().asCharBuffer().get(result);
    return result;
}

That said, this is a rather weird requirement. If you want to send some bytes in text form, I'd suggest base 64 encoding it.

Thanks it works, and this is exactly what I want and more concise than what I achieved.

@Sweeper I think Mac OS Roman has no 'holes'

Using approaches similar to yours you can also do it like this.  It also accepts character arrays shorter than four characters.
long result = asciiToLong("abcd".toCharArray());
System.out.println(result);
char[] arr = longToAscii(result);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
 

public static char[] longToAscii(long in) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     while (in != 0) {
         sb.insert(0, (char) (in & 0xFF));
         in >>= 16;
     }
     return sb.toString().toCharArray();
 }

 public static long asciiToLong(char[] in) {
     long v = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(Long.BYTES / 2, in.length); i++) {
         v = v << 16 | in[i];
     }
     return v;
 }

prints
27303493654216804
[a, b, c, d]

